# Animate many images on iPhone/iPad

Tags: image, ios4, animation, nstimer

I made subclass of UIView and override drawRect method that drawing jpg images. For animation i'm using a NSTimes which fires 24 times per second. But animation playin slow than i expected. How can i improve frame rate. Please provide me a drawing code that run fast.